# Start-Process Access denied with domain\admin privileges

Tags: powershell

I get an "access denied" error when I want to start a process on a remote computer, even though I'm connecting to the RemoteComputer as a domain admin (which is proven by the output of `whoami` in the code which gives me the correct `domain\admin`)

```
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Admin, $PW
foreach ($c in $ComputerName) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $c -Credential $cred -ArgumentList $cred,$exepath,$exeargs {
        param($cred,$exepath,$exeargs)
            whoami
        if (!$exeargs) { Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $cred  }
        else { Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $cred <#other stuff #> }
    }
}
```

I saw many question on Stack Overflow regarding this question, but there never really is an answer which helps with this error, only workarounds. (Questions like [Powershell Start-Process : This command cannot be executed due to the error: Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912320/powershell-start-process-this-command-cannot-be-executed-due-to-the-error-acc) and [Access-Denied error upon using start-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111993/access-denied-error-upon-using-start-process))

Why do i get an access denied, when trying to start powershell.exe as a domain admin on a remote computer?